# How to Decompile Bytenode "jsc" files?

Tags: node.js, v8, bytecode, decompiling

I've just seen this library **[ByteNode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytenode)** it's the same as ByteCode of java but this is for NodeJS.

This library compiles your JavaScript code into V8 bytecode, which protect your source code, I'm wondering is there anyway to Decompile byteNode therefore it's not secure enough. I'm wondering because I would like to protect my source code using this library?

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** It'll raise the bar to someone copying the code and trying to pass it off as their own. It won't prevent a dedicated person from doing so. But the primary way to protect your work isn't technical, it's legal.

---

> This library compiles your JavaScript code into V8 bytecode, which protect your source code...

Well, we don't know it's V8 bytecode, but it's "compiled" in *some* sense. All we know is that it creates a "code cache" via the built-in [`vm.Script.prototype.createCachedData`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_createcacheddata) API, which is officially just a cache used to *speed up* recompiling the code a second time, third time, etc. In theory, you're supposed to also provide the original source code as a string to [the `vm.Script` constructor](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_constructor_new_vm_script_code_options). But if you go digging into Node.js's `vm.Script` and V8 far enough it seems to be the actual code in some compiled form (whether actual V8 bytecode or not), and the code string you give it when running is ignored. (The ByteNode library provides a dummy string when running the code from the code cache, so clearly the actual code isn't [always?] needed.)

> I'm wondering is there anyway to Decompile byteNode therefore it's not secure enough.

Naturally, otherwise it would be useless because Node.js wouldn't be able to run it. I didn't find a tool to do it that already exists, but since V8 is open source, it would presumably be possible to find the necessary information to write a decompiler for it that outputs valid JavaScript source code which someone could then try to understand.

Experimenting with it, local variable names appear to be lost, although function names don't. Comments appear to get lost (this may not be as obvious as it seems, given that `Function.prototype.toString` is required to either return the original source text or a synthetic version [[details]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.tostring)).

So if you run the code through a minifier (particularly one that renames functions), then run it through ByteNode (or just do it with `vm.Script` yourself, ByteNode is a fairly thin wrapper), it will be *feasible* for someone to decompile it into something resembling source code, but that source code will be very hard to understand. This is very similar to shipping Java class files, which can be decompiled (there's even a standard tool to do it in the JDK, `javap`), except that the format Java class files are well-documented and don't change from one dot release to the next (though they can change from one major release to another; new releases always support the older format, though), whereas the format of this data is not documented (though it's an open source project) and **is** subject to change from one dot release to the next.

Certain changes, such as changing the copyright message, are probably fairly easy to make to said source code. More meaningful changes will be harder.

Note that the code cache appears to have a checksum or other similar integrity mechanism, since directly editing the `.jsc` file to swap one letter for another in a literal string makes the code cache fail to load. So someone tampering with it (for instance, to change a copyright notice) would either need to go the decompilation/recompilation route, or dive into the V8 source to find out how to correct the integrity check.

---

Fundamentally, the way to protect your work is to ensure that you've put all the relevant notices in the relevant places such that the fact copying it is a violation of copyright is clear, then pursue your legal recourse should you find out about someone passing it off as their own.

Comment: Fundamentally +1. One comment: the ByteNode approach knowingly/intentionally breaks `Function.prototype.toString`, it'll return garbage. If your code relies on `F.p.toString`, then you can't use ByteNode, period. Also, there is no copyright notice in the cached data, so if someone wanted to sell *that* as their own, they wouldn't even need to tamper with it.

Comment: @jmrk :-)  I was assuming there'd be a copyright notice somewhere in a string literal in the code (which is, of course, in the cache), for displaying when the app starts, or in response to `--help`, or just so that it's there in the code somewhere (I always do that in binary-distribution apps). Good point about `Function.prototype.toString`. (I've always thought relying on it was an anti-pattern, but it's specified now...)

Comment: 100% agree with you, just find it frustrating when people say "pursue your legal recourse". This fine if your a big company but ridiculously expensive if your not. Taking a legal route sucks for a single developer trying to push boundaries and protect code. I had a similar situation all they tell you is to contact the company and tell them to remove the code or you will seek legal action thats your only real defence unless you have a tonne of money to throw at lawyers and legal fees. Big companies always win in this situation.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089746/is-node-bytecode-decompilable-because-the-interpreter-is-open-source) is a question asking for clarification of the "*since V8 is open source, it would presumably be possible […] to write a decompiler*" part

Answer (score 5):

> is there any way

You could get a hundred answers here saying "I don't *know* a way", but that still won't guarantee that there *isn't* one.

> not secure enough

Secure enough for what? What's your deployment scenario? What kind of scenario/attack are you trying to defend against?

FWIW, I don't *know* of an existing tool that "decompiles" V8 bytecode (i.e. produces JavaScript source code with the same behavior). That said, considering that the bytecode is a fairly straightforward translation of the source code, I'm sure it wouldn't be very hard to write such a tool, if someone had a reason to spend some time on it. After all, V8's JS-to-bytecode compiler is open source, so one would only have to look at those sources and implement the reverse direction. So I would assume that shipping as bytecode provides about as much "protection" as shipping as uglified JavaScript, i.e. none that I would trust.

Before you make any decisions, please also keep in mind that bytecode is considered an internal implementation detail of V8; in particular it is not versioned and can change at any time, so it has to be created by exactly the same V8 version that consumes it. If you want to update your Node.js you'll have to recreate all the bytecode, and there is no checking or warning in place that will point out when you forgot to do that.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear from the beginning, since bytecode protect your source code, is it secure enough and really capable of protecting the source code. I have a source code that I'm selling and I want to make sure nobody will decompile and sell my source code.

I was thinking about make a v8 environment to decompile the code, but wanted some idea and starting lines.

Comment: You are looking for a technical solution to a legal problem. And only you can define if it’s “secure enough” for you. Locks are measured in how long it takes a locksmith to break in. No lock is reated to infinity minutes. A good lock takes about 5 minutes. decompiling v8 is a ton of effort. Yes, I could do it, but I’m pretty sure it would be cheaper to just rewrite whatever module you are selling.

Comment: V8's bytecode is not designed to be an obfuscation mechanism (ByteNode is a hack that abuses a caching system for another purpose), so it doesn't even try to make decompilation difficult. I guess one could write a pretty good decompiler for it in maybe a week of work. Maybe someone out there even has one already...

Answer (score 3):

Node.js source already contains code for decompiling binary bytecode.
You can get a text string from your V8 bytecode and then you would need to analyze it.
But text string would be very long and miss some important information such as a constant pool. So you need to modify the Node.js source.
Please check https://github.com/3DGISKing/pkg10.17.0
I have attached exported xml file.
If you study V8, it would be possible to analyze it and get source code from it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It keeping it short and sweet, You can try [Ghidra](https://github.com/PositiveTechnologies/ghidra_nodejs) node.js package which is based on **[Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/)** reverse engineering framework which was open-sourced by [NSA](https://www.nsa.gov/) in the year 2019. Ghidra is capable of disassembling and decompiling the v8 bytecode. The inner working of disassembling is quite complex, this answer is short but sufficient.

Comment: I tried ghidra_nodejs but it seems that the extension works for only  jsc files of which v8 version is a 6.2.414.77