# Is Node Bytecode decompilable because the interpreter is open source?

Tags: node.js, security, v8, bytecode

I've been doing a lot of reading on V8 Bytecode, specifically [Bytenode](https://github.com/bytenode/bytenode) and [Electron-Vite's implementation](https://electron-vite.org/guide/source-code-protection#customizing-protection), and how they are advertised as a way to protect source code, but that doesn't actually seem to be the case.

Reading [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57052153/how-to-decompile-bytenode-jsc-files) suggests that decompiling Bytecode would be possible due to being able to see V8's JS-to-bytecode compiler, thus, being able to reverse the operation.

Alongside that, it seems a decompiler was actually created, and is available [here](https://github.com/PositiveTechnologies/ghidra_nodejs). Although it is outdated, I'm guessing it could be done again with updated versions of V8. [This article](https://swarm.ptsecurity.com/how-we-bypassed-bytenode-and-decompiled-node-js-bytecode-in-ghidra/) describes the process used to create the decompiler and seems to have a good understanding of the inner workings of the interpreter, and, without that insight, it seems it would've been much harder to create the decompiler.

My question is this, if someone didn't know how the interpreter worked, would V8 bytecode be un-decompilable and considered "secure"? Secure here meaning the same as modern day encryption, i.e. the time to brute force / guess how the interpreter worked would be so long that it is considered secure.

Comment: Of course not "secure" in the sense of encryption. You don't need to know source code to decompile things. It is harder, but not even close to modern encryption. It is security by obscurity, nothing else. Besides, you don't need to know how interpreter works, you only need to know the bytecode. Which is a lot less.

Comment: @freakish so if you were given a .jsc file (compiled JS to bytecode file), and no information on the interpreter, it still wouldn't be that hard to create a decompiler for it?

Comment: Again: you don't need to know interpreter, only bytecode definition. Or if you have enough files and can do something with them (e.g. run them) then reverse engineering becomes possible. Without any information it is close to impossible. But the point is that you won't be able to decrypt things **regardless** of whether you know the method or not. That is not comparable at all to any decompilation.

Comment: Since V8 is and remains open source, I'm not sure what the point of the question is. Even if the answer was "yes" (which it isn't), what would that change? V8's bytecode is definitely not designed to hide secrets, and I'm pretty doubtful that designing an interpreter whose bytecode is un-decompilable is even possible (open source or not). Realistically, bytecode is as "secure" as minified JS: hard to read, but a skilled engineer with tools could decipher it. For selling your customers a feel-good idea of "here, look, your precious proprietary code is unreadable", that may be enough...

Comment: @freakish The mention of encryption was just for the idea that security is measured in time. I know that it would be possible to reverse engineer the interpreter and decompile it eventually, but I was more curious on how long that may take given no understanding of the interpreter. But I guess that question is hard to give even a somewhat accurate answer for given how many different variables could influence it.

Comment: @TylerWanta I think you misunderstand what I'm saying. Noone decompiles interpreter to learn bytecode. It is even unlikely that people read source code to understand bytecode (maybe only to check some nasty details). Just like you don't read compiler/interpreter source code to learn JS or any other language. Typically those things are documented. Otherwise can you imagine maintenance nightmare of such project? So all you need to do is to find documentation, no reverse engineering is required.

Comment: And yes, without any information bytecode is just a sequence of bytes, impossible to understand. Without any information it is pointless and useless. But so is encryption. You won't be able to decrypt things if you at least don't know the algorithm that was used to encrypt it.

Comment: So proper "time comparison" makes sense only if you have the same initial information. In that sense decompilation is trivial, decryption impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If somehow I didn't know how the interpreter worked, would V8 bytecode be un-decompilable and considered "secure".

No.

Actually, taken literally, yes, building the decompiler is not possible without understanding how the interpretation works. However, understanding how an interpreter works does not require it to be open-source. That does definitely help, but it would also be possible to reverse-engineer the interpreter to gain this understanding without source code or documentation access. Maybe decompile the interpreter executable first :-) This is always possible to do as long as you are able to execute the (compiled) JS program, given to you as bytecode plus interpreter executable.
This has nothing to do with brute-forcing, and is not comparable to cryptographical security - there is only obfuscation. It's straightforward engineering - it may require hiring costly specialists, but it's not "unbreakable".

In the end, [every language (that you understand) can be (de)compiled](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/3608/946) back to JavaScript. You may still not be able to make sense of that JS code since it may have lost variable names, comments, and parts of the structure, but some things (like property names or calls to runtime builtins) will have been preserved and you can have a go at reverse-engineering the bytecode.

Comment: "Literally" you don't need to know interpreter to decompile bytecode. You only need to know bytecode definition, the grammar and semantics of the language. That's all.

Comment: @freakish That's what I mean by "*understanding how the interpreter works*". Let me clarify by changing it to "*interpretation*" - it's also possible from bytecode language documentation/specification without a concrete interpreter indeed.